# How to apply multiple filters to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, filter, web-parts

I have sharepoint list with several columns - month, year and some custom data. I want to provide 2 dropdowns to allow user select month and year to filter rows.

1. I added "Choice Filter" webpart for month and set connection to list (this works).
2. I added second "Choice Filter" for year and I wanted to do the same. However, I cannot set connection to list, because mylist is disabled in webpart menu "Edit->Connections->Send filter values to".

How can I apply 2 filtering criteria?

Thanks,

Juraj

Answer (score 4):

The List View WEbpart allows only 1 connection at a time ([source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA102509891033.aspx), look at the notes under the "Ways to filter a List View Wep Part" header) so the described approach won't work. There is a work around though: by using the Data **View** WEbPart (DVWP or DFWP (Data Form webpart as it is sometimes called)) through SharePoint Designer to create a webpart that mimics a list view.

The DVWP ships with all versions of sharepoint and is basically a regular gridview, and  pretty much the most customizable webpart there is when it comes to displaying list data.